# Append value in the class name specified into html code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after click on button append value `hello 2` in tag `td` with class name `subpage` and append value `hello 3` in class name `tdadeps` wit find it class in html code that is in var obj and in end append var obj whit values in `.wfnish tbody`, it doesn't work in my try, how can fix it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yxKFX/1/

My try:

```
$('button').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.wfnish').show();

    var obj = '<tr><td>hello 1</td><td class="subpage"></td><td class="tdadeps"></td></tr>';

    $(obj, '.subpage').append('hello 2');
    $(obj, '.tdadeps').append('hello 3');

    $('.wfnish tbody').append(obj);    
})
```

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense the way its phrased. can you try to clarify?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `.find()`.

```
var obj = $('<tr><td>hello 1</td><td class="subpage"></td><td class="tdadeps"></td></tr>');

obj.find('.subpage').append('hello 2');
obj.find('.tdadeps').append('hello 3');
```

You'll also notice that I stored the result of passing the HTML string. This is required because the original string is never modified.

---

If you really want to use the second argument to the jQuery function, you have them reversed:

```
$('.subpage', obj).append('hello 2');
```

Under the hood, this is analyzed then reinvoked as the `.find()` code above.

Answer (score 0):

Parse obj once into a jQuery wrapped variable and then use find to make the changed. Or alternatively just interpolate it into the string.

```
$('button').live('click', function (e) {
    ...
    var $obj = $('<tr><td>hello 1</td><td class="subpage"></td><td class="tdadeps"></td></tr>');

    $obj.find('.subpage').append('hello 2');
    $obj.find('.tdadeps').append('hello 3');
    $('.wfnish tbody').append($obj);    
});
```

Or,

```
$('button').live('click', function (e) {
    ...
    $('.wfnish tbody').append(
          '<tr><td>hello 1</td><td class="subpage">'
        + 'hello 2'
        + '</td><td class="tdadeps">'
        + 'hello 3'
        + '</td></tr>'
    );   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.wfnish').show();

    var obj = '<tr><td>hello 1</td><td class="subpage"></td><td class="tdadeps"></td></tr>';


    $('.wfnish tbody').append(obj);    

    $('td.subpage').html('hello 2');
    $('td.tdadeps').html('hello 3');
})
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yxKFX/2/

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the sequence:

```
$('button').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.wfnish').show();

    var obj = '<tr><td>hello 1</td><td class="subpage"></td><td class="tdadeps"></td></tr>';

    $('.wfnish tbody').append(obj); 
    $('.subpage').append('hello 2');
    $('.tdadeps').append('hello 3');
});
```